# Can't upload file > 4MiB on SMB share

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba, smb

for a few weeks now, I no longer can upload files to my Samba server. I didn't changed the configuration nor update Samba for it to happens. I had Samba 4.1.5 when it happened, so I tried to update to 4.1.7 but the problem remains. I'm on Mageia Cauldron, with Samba 4 manually compiled an configured as a PDC.

I can download files from the Samba share without any problem, from a few bytes to several GiB between 8.8 and 11.2MiB/s. But I can only upload files smaller than ~4MiB, and slower than 100KiB/s. When I copy from GNU/Linux I get a timeout error, and when I copy from Windows, it says the network name is no longer available.

Any idea on how to solve this ? Here is my smb.conf if it's useful:

```
[global]
workgroup = DOMAIN.ORG
server string = Samba Server Version %v

realm = AD.DOMAIN.ORG

netbios name = DOMAIN
server role = active directory domain controller
server services = s3fs, rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate
idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes


encrypt passwords = yes
log level = 3
log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
max log size = 50
template shell = /bin/bash

logon drive = P:
logon home = \\192.168.1.2\Profiles\%U
logon path = \\192.168.1.2\Profiles\%U

load printers = yes
printing = cups

[printers]
path = /var/spool/samba
browseable=yes
printable = yes
public = yes

[print$]
path = /srv/samba/Printer_drivers
comment = Printer Drivers
writeable = yes

[Data]
path = /mnt/data
read only = No

[profile]
path = /srv/samba/profile
read only = no
profile acls = yes
create mode = 0600
directory mode = 0700
browseable = no

[netlogon]
path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/ad.domain.org/scripts
read only = No

[sysvol]
path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
read only = No

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
writable = yes
force create mode = 0660
force directory mode = 0770

[Profiles]
path = /srv/samba/Profiles/
read only = no
msdfs root = yes

[IPC$]
path = %$TMPDIR
guest ok = yes
#hosts allow = 192.168.1.0/24 127.0.0.1 fe80::250:22ff:fe40:1048/64
#hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0
```

Comment: Have you tried downgrading the package?

Comment: Downgrading to what ?

Comment: To an earlier version, also, check the answer I've proposed.

Comment: Not a solution, but after changing distribution (ArchLinux now) the problem seems to be solved. Note that I kept all the data, including Samba configuration and databases. Although I can't get full upload and download rate (doesn't go past 9MB/s), it must be a damaged Ethernet cable.

Comment: What is the package version you were using on both distros, respectively? I suspect it was a bug. I also suggest you give a try to fedora, there are lots of support and packages are almost always bleeding edge.

Comment: I had 4.1.5 to 4.1.7 on Mageia where the bug appeared. With ArchLinux, I had originally 4.1.7 too, then 4.1.8 and now 4.1.9. The bug never appeared. I would rather think it was a bug in another package. (kernel maybe ? already had problems with networking, and two of my laptops have problems with r8169, on different distributions.) I have Fedora on most desktops/laptops, but on the server I need some specific packages like ndppd and some specific tweaks : ArchLinux is better for that. (now I have a compatibility issue with Shorewall and Perl 5.20, but that's another problem)

Answer (score 0):

There's an option in the `smb.conf` file which disables the delay before timeout for TCP connections (which may be ocurring since the connection lasts *too long* on larger files and it thinks it's not responding, maybe because of a bug on that build), just add:

> socket options = TCP_NODELAY

To your conf file and test.
[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/443557/ubuntu-12-04-samba-file-server-timeout-on-large-file).

Also try downgrading your package to the last working version, if it's possible for you.

*Update, regarding your last comments*:

Regarding your speed part, I'll assume you have 2 `100 Mbps` NICs on each end connected to a `100 Mbps` HUB or switch, so If you do some math we get that:

```
100 Mbps = 100 Mbits / 8 bytes/bit = 12.5 MB/s max.
```

And assuming your switch or NICs aren't full-duplex (like a WiFi network), you should get an speed of ~6.25 MB/s for TCP transmissions, but I think it's not the case, either way, always assume the slow-down that is caused by other traffic running through the network, specially if you're on a HUB where collisions commonly occur.

Also note that `100 MB/s ≠ 100 MiB/s`:

```
100 `MB/s` = 100,000,000 b = 100*10^6 b ← Base 10.
```

Where:

```
100 `MiB/s` = 104,857,600 b = 100*2^20 b ← Base 2.
```

So of your connection tops at `12.5 MB/s` and your tool is measuring it in terms of `MiB` (which most common tools do), you have that:

```
12.5 MB/s = 12,500,000 b
12,500,000 b / 2^20 B = ~12 MiB/s
```

And if you factor in the slow-downs of traffic on a real network, there's your real speed.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and those are just theorical speeds. The CPU and network load also influence the real speed. In practice I was getting a max of 11,2MiB/s. Now I'm below 9MiB/s, so I lost more than 2MiB/s, but since someone crushed the Ethernet cable between the server and the (100Mb/s) switch, it might have been a bit damaged. I will run some iperf tests, and the cable should be replaced this summer (and migrating from 100Mb/s to 1Gb/s).